# Auditoria de dados

Tags: demoiselle

Tenho duas dúvidas.

Estou seguindo o PDF de auditoria (http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/components/audit/reference/1.0.4/pdf/demoiselle-audit-reference.pdf) porém meu maven não encontra a versão 1.0.3. É exibido somente a 1.0.0 Snap. A versão foi retirada ou é algum erro aqui no meu indexamento ?

Utilizo a versão 2.5 do projeto e ao tentar utilizar auditoria ocorre o erro:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.User.

Auditoria funciona somente até a versão 2.4 ?

Answer (score 1):

Realmente este componente só funciona até a versão 2.4 do Demoiselle. Acabou que não saiu da forma esperada e por enquanto está "congelado". Para versão 2.5 é possível usar o Envers http://hibernate.org/orm/envers e tenho um exemplo bem simples do uso dele neste link: https://github.com/esaito/ExemplosDemoiselle/tree/master/envers